# Send PMs in Tandem ( Parallel ) using Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, parallel-processing, celery

###### Problem

Please tell me how to do Django tasks in parallel, like I've 3 accounts sending 3 forms at same time, each form on one account, **I want the forms to be sent at the same time on the background**. Currently, I'm sending the forms with celery on background, **I just want them to run on parallel instead of a queue**.

###### Info

When I send a form, it sends private messages using **selenium** to many users from a csv file

###### Without Celery

It works great without celery, and they send in parallel but I'm trying to get them work on background due to heavy loads on the server

###### Tried to run the server with daphne ( ASGI instead of WSGI ) but didn't help

Comment: You should take a look of `asgi` instead of `wsgi`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/asgi/

Comment: @CallMarl I tried to use daphne , and I tried submitting two forms and it's not in parallel

Comment: @CallMarl If I tried async , will it work ?